# Обробка данных при ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$("p").load('x.php');
```

x.php

```
  echo time();
```

А как обработать результат чтобы сделать манипуляции с переданным значением и   записать в innerHTML тега p?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

и так что мы имеем: jQuery.load открываем документацию и читаем, что load имеет 3 параметра.

1. url
2. данные
3. функция

про url мы знаем все. Про данные надо знать что они передаются либо парами либо строкой первый будет слать POST второй Get. Дальше к третьему параметру перейдем. **функция**

```
function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
  this; // dom element
}
```

Вот в ней как раз все можно и обработать.
UPD: Второй и третий параметры не обязательны т.е. функция может стоят на втором месте.

Answer (score 2):

в js

```
$.ajax({
    url    : 'ajax.php',
    type   : "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = data;
    }
});
```

в php

```
<?
header('Content-Type: application/json');
print_r('я див');
```

UPD
http://jsfiddle.net/DNCws/1/

Comment: Да это правильно не спорю.А через метод load и обработчик можно?

Comment: @zloctb обновил